# JavaScript - .then() chain not queued up

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Theoretical example regarding .then() syntax...

Why doesn't it wait for the second call to resolve before calling the third?

```js
// Waits ms milliseconds then resolves
const fn = (ms) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(()=>res(console.log(`Resolved after ${ms} ms delay`)), ms);
    });
}

console.log(`calling fn #1`);
fn(2000).then(()=>{
    console.log(`calling fn #2`);
    fn(2000);
}).then(()=>{
    console.log(`calling fn #3`);
    fn(2000);
});
```

This is the output

```
// calling fn #1
// Resolved after 2000 second delay
// calling fn #2
// calling fn #3
// Resolved after 2000 second delay
// Resolved after 2000 second delay
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to chain you *must* `return` a promise or else it's presumed to be something that's not relevant to the chain:

```js
console.log(`calling fn #1`);
fn1(2000).then(()=>{
    console.log(`calling fn #2`);
    return fn(2000);
}).then(()=>{
    console.log(`calling fn #3`);
    return fn(2000);
});
```

Also if you want the `await` form it looks like this:

```js
async function example() {
  console.log(`calling fn #1`);
  await fn1(2000);

  console.log(`calling fn #2`);
  await fn(2000);

  console.log(`calling fn #3`);
  await fn(2000);
};
```

Which honestly is a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using 'await' this should work

```
await fn(2000);
```